# Produce evenly spaced values on a logarithmic scale (like `np.linspace()`, but on a log scale)

Tags: python, numpy

I want to creat two samples, first an y sample with values in a range from 10^3 to 10^10 and another x sample with values in a range from 10^-5 to 10^10 for a logarithmic plot. I tried the following :

```
y = np.linspace(1e3,1e10, num = 1000)
x = np.linspace(1e-5,1e10, num = 1000)
```

but it returns me a non evenly distributed sample, with only 1 value of the order of 10^-5 and many more of the order of 10^9 for x, and zero value between 10^-5 and 10^7. That is what I get for x:

```
 [1.00000000e-05 1.00100100e+07 2.00200200e+07 3.00300300e+07
 4.00400400e+07 5.00500501e+07 6.00600601e+07 7.00700701e+07
 8.00800801e+07 9.00900901e+07 1.00100100e+08 1.10110110e+08
 1.20120120e+08 1.30130130e+08 1.40140140e+08 1.50150150e+08
 ...
```

I want a sample with values evenly separated: with the same number of values for each 10^ order because I need it for a logarithmic plot. Why is linspace not working and how can I fix it ?

Comment: people who voted this down: I can't know everything, thank you for bringing new people to coding down. This was a real strugle for me I googled it but could not find anything and I coulnd know that there is an extra  code for sample for log plot. And the thing that i could not find anything about non evenly distributed sample is because people like you vote down such topic which are interesting and useful for people with this problem.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I just simply googled very basic "logarithmic scale values python" and on the very first page, it showed me the numpy logspace result. I do not know how this was a "real strugle" for you and why you write "I googled it but could not find anything"

Comment: well because i googled 'non evenly distributed valued with linspace' and did not find anything. Of course I would have find it if I had google like you, but for this I should have already know that there is a code for that, which I didnt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the wrong function for what you are trying to achieve here. You should use "logspace" for that.

```
y = np.logspace(3,10, num = 1000)
print (y)
```

Answer (score 6):

A `linspace` returns linearly spaced values, meaning there will be the same distance from each number to the next.
`logspace` on the other hand creates logarithmically spaced values, which are what you are looking for.
https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.logspace.html

Edit:
Beware that `logspace` takes the exponent as start and stop values. Meaning you must write `np.logspace(3, 10, num = 1000)` and `np.logspace(-5, 10, num = 1000)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Oh ok I see. But i don't understand how this values are linearly spaced. Also I tried with logspace, and it returned me an array with inf..... Why is that :(

Comment: You need to rewrite your code as @ReardedHorse suggested:
np.logspace(3, 10, num = 1000) 
np.logspace(-5, 10, num = 1000)

Comment: Linearly spaced means there is the same distance between the given values, e.g. [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19... 101, 104, 107, 110] gives the same number of values in 0-10, as there is in 10-20. But you want e.g. 10 values from 0-10 and 10 values from 10-100 and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [geomspace](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html#numpy.geomspace):

```
import numpy as np

y = np.geomspace(1e3, 1e10, num=8)

print(y)
```

```
[1.e+03 1.e+04 1.e+05 1.e+06 1.e+07 1.e+08 1.e+09 1.e+10]
```